# Pandas dataframe set_index KeyError:

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

When importing a csv file I can't seem to set the index. I can't work out if am importing the file correctly, I am doing everything in the interpreter currently, here is what I have:

```
df = pd.read_csv('E:/test.vbo', sep='\t', encoding='iso-8859-1', skiprows=97)
print(df.head())
```

this give the following:

```
     sats time lat long velocity heading height ...
0                                                                  [data]
1    008 144403.30 003067.21791 000031.98044 010.033 097.16 +00112.43 ...
2    008 144403.40 003067.21777 000031.98036 010.584 098.58 +00113.06 ...
3    008 144403.50 003067.21765 000031.98032 010.809 099.74 +00113.72 ...
4    008 144403.60 003067.21749 000031.98025 011.231 101.05 +00114.34 ...
5    008 144403.70 003067.21728 000031.98021 011.575 102.14 +00114.89 ...
```

Which is fine, however, this line:
print(df.set_index('time'))

give an error:

```
>>> print(df.set_index('time'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rob.kinsey\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\
pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1945, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.g
et_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.g
et_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'time'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rob.kinsey\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\
pandas\core\frame.py", line 2837, in set_index
    level = frame[col]._values
  File "C:\Users\rob.kinsey\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\
pandas\core\frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\rob.kinsey\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\
pandas\core\frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\rob.kinsey\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\
pandas\core\generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\rob.kinsey\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\
pandas\core\internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\rob.kinsey\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\
pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.g
et_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.g
et_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'time'
>>>
```

What am I missing please?

```
>>> print(df.columns.tolist())
['sats time lat long velocity heading height vert-vel dgps racceleratorpedal ast
eeringwheel pbrake glateral glongitudinal awingpitch ngearengaged nengine nwheel
fr nwheelrr nwheelfl nwheelrl mengine rdrsavailabledisplayed pwaterpump toil tdc
dc tmotorstator phvac nephsmotor pboost taircharge tcoolant tclutchoil nephspump
demanded tcellmax vbattery paerooil taerooil tmcucoldplate awingpitchdemand tmcu
_igbtmax avifileindex avitime ']
```

Solved, here is the correct read_csv line:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('E:/vbox_data/P1GTR__20150922144312_0001.vbo', delim_whitespace=True, encoding='iso-8859-1', header=90)
```

Comment: what does your raw data look like? What does `print(df.columns.tolist())`  show? your df looks strange, your column names are probably not what you think they are

Comment: >>> print(df.columns.tolist())
['sats time lat long velocity heading height vert-vel dgps racceleratorpedal ast
eeringwheel pbrake glateral glongitudinal awingpitch ngearengaged nengine nwheel
fr nwheelrr nwheelfl nwheelrl mengine rdrsavailabledisplayed pwaterpump toil tdc
dc tmotorstator phvac nephsmotor pboost taircharge tcoolant tclutchoil nephspump
demanded tcellmax vbattery paerooil taerooil tmcucoldplate awingpitchdemand tmcu
_igbtmax avifileindex avitime ']

Comment: Edit this into your question, the formatting is lost, besides it looks like you have a single column which is why your code failed, this may mean the separator in your file is not a tab

Comment: Apologies, edited, the formatting is how it looks on my command prompt

Comment: Its always good to inspect your dataframe with commands like `df.shape, df.info(), df.head(), df.describe()`

Comment: Thank you, you have solved my issue, it was indeed white space separated and not tab separated, I am now able to use the headers as expected. Kind regards iFunk